# how to show bottom sheet of google material always on top of key board

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

i have done the implementation of com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior and i want to show the whole bottom sheet on top of keyBoard when user click for searching.
help will be appreciated thanks

here is my image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in your manifest of your Activity or create a style for the BottomSheet that contains this item `<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>`?

Comment: do you mean you want the bottom sheet to expand and fill the entire screen when the user activates the edit text for typing?

Comment: @skizo i have already tried but not working

Comment: @jayhymn  i want when press on etText the bottom of sheet should be on the top of key board

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

to the `onCreateView()` of your bottom fragment could be a potential fix.